# Shop By Price not Showing Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I am showing `Shop By Price` on left sidebar. In `Configuration → Catalog → Catalog → Layered Navigation` i have `Price Navigation Step Calculation` to `Manual` and `Default Price Navigation Step` to `100`and `Maximum Number of Price Intervals` is `5`.
The `anchor` option in the `Categories` are `Yes`.
Also In `Managed Attributes` `price` -> `Use In Layered Navigation` is `Filterable (with results)`.
But `Shop By Price` Not Showing.

Comment: remove var/cache folder and refresh all index management.

Comment: i have flushed cache, and also refresh index managment. But still not showing.

Comment: try to add to any of your category url following: _?dir=asc&order=price_ if filter applies successfully - it's cache issue.

Comment: i have tried. still no luck. :(

Comment: Do you have products in your category ? Have you tried on the native default/default theme ?

Comment: yes i have products and yes i have checked on rwd and default theme. on default theme, only shop by category is showing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug, reported here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3209